# $A \otimes_k A \to \bigwedge^2 A$ homs

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Let $k$ be a unital commutative ring, and A be a $k$-module.
Is there a homomorphism $f: A \otimes_k A \to \bigwedge^2 A$ such that $f(a \otimes a) \neq 0$ for some $a \in A$? I can take a hint :)

**Motivation**:
In his textbook on Lie algebra, Serre defines a Lie algebra as a k-module with a homomorphism $A \otimes_k A \to A$ that factors through $\Lambda^2 A$. He then goes on to explain that it means that [x,x]=0 for all $x \in A$.

Comment: Sure, take k to be a field and just pick a random linear map. What's the point of this question?

Comment: In his textbook on Lie algebra, Serre defines a Lie algebra as a k-module with a homomorphism $A \otimes_k A \to A$ that factors through $\bigwedge^2 A$. He then goes on to explain that it means that $[x,x] = 0$ for all $x \in A$. I have problem with that, that's why I asked.

Comment: please add the motivation to the question itself.

Comment: What Serre means is that the map factorizes through the *canonical* map $A\otimes A\to\Lambda^2A$ (which sends $a\otimes b$ to $a\wedge b$)

Comment: That explains it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Serre means is the following.  You probably know that the tangent square $A \otimes_k A$ is universal for $k$-bilinear maps out of $A \times A$.  The exterior square $\Lambda^2 A$ is universal for *alternating* $k$-bilinear maps out of $A \times A$.  Any such map is first of all a $k$-bilinear map, so it factors through $A \otimes_k A$.  But the alternating property causes it to further factor through the *natural* quotient $A \otimes_k A \to \Lambda^2 A$.  Serre has in mind a specific map here.

Answer (score 0):

**This answer is no loger relevant, since the OP now asked (in a comment...) what he had meant to askm which happens not to be what he asked :)**

There obviously exist examples of $k$s and $A$s such that such homomorphisms do exist (take, for example, $A$ free of rank at least $2$ over $k$...)

Now it is not true that such homomorphisms exist for all choices of $k$ and $A$ (take, for example, $A$ free of rank $1$...)

I am not sure neither of these facts is what you intended to ask, though.

**Later:** one thing you might have intended to ask if there is such a homomorphism depending *naturally* on $A$. The answer to that is also no, because of my second example above.